# MasterDetailPage and NavigationPage combination within Xamarin

Tags: c#, xamarin, navigation, xamarin.forms, master-detail

I'm creating a Xamarin application where I want to combine multiple pages, the `MasterDetailPage` and the `NavigationPage`.

My `MainPage` contains the `MasterDetailPage`, the master of the `MasterDetailPage` contains a list of views (custom class which stores information such as the class type, image to show and the name) the user can view. Those views are all `ContentPage`s. When an item of the list is clicked, the `ContentPage` gets initialized by using reflection and is then stored within the `MasterDetailPage`. At the moment everything has been made as Xamarin suggests.

But one of those `ContentPages` contains a `ListView`.

[image: Example of the ListView]

When an item has been selected, the `ListView` has to open a detailview and the user must be able to return to the `ListView`. Because of that I'm using the `Navigation` class and push the page within the `NavigationPage`, as following (binding can be done better, but it's just to get feeling with Xamarin):

```
private async Task Handle_ItemSelected(object sender, Xamarin.Forms.SelectedItemChangedEventArgs e)
{
        if (_detail == null)
        {
            _detail = new Detail();

        }
        _detail.BindingContext = SelectedTrack;
        await Navigation.PushAsync(new NavigationPage(_detail));
}
```

When done like this, the *Back* button is rendered above the `MasterDetailPage`.

[image: Example of the NavigationPage]

Is there any way I can remove the 'burger' button of the MasterDetailPage when going to the `ListView`'s detail page? Or am I currently using the wrong workflow?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Set your detail page as NavigationPage.

```
_masterDetailPage.Detail = new NavigationPage(page);
```

Or

```
MainPage = new MasterDetailPage
            {
                Master = new MyMasterPage(),
                Detail = new NavigationPage(MyHomePage())
            });
```

And then in your from detail view you can Navigate to your other pages by :

```
await Navigation.PushAsync(new NavigationPage(_detail));
```

You will see back button and not Hamburger.

Have a look at the [sample](https://github.com/rohitvipin/XFMasterDetailDemo).

Comment: The page in the Detail property of the MasterDetailPage is already within a navigation page.

Comment: I have added a sample project, please have a look.

Comment: Sorry for the late answer, hadn't had much time. I've taken a look at your example and I do put the page within a Navigationpage in the detail.

Comment: Wanted to say it got solved by putting my initial NavigationPage into codebehind instead of XAML, which is in my opinion odd.